# Wrong notification time showing in app (Google FCM)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can somebody help please, I have Google FCM integrated in my Java app so when I send any notification from my admin panel, on receiving notification in app it shows wrong time under notification as 10 hrs. How to fix it?

Google for solutions but nothing found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can share what code implementation have you done and what specific blocker are you experiencing. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).